# Lines not showing up on cfchart

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cfchart

I am using XML styling to draw 2 lines on my cfchart. For some unknown reason, the lines are not showing up. I have done this before with different charts and never had this problem.

The code:

```
<cfset xmlStyle = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><frameChart is3D="false">
  <frame type="none" isHStripVisible="true" stripColor="##F0F9FF" outline="black"/>
    <elements drawOutline="false" drawShadow="true">
       <series index="0">
            <paint color="##00AEEF"/>
       </series>
  </elements>
    <paint paint="Plain"/>
    <xAxis>
      <labelStyle orientation="Slanted"/>
    </xAxis>
    <insets left="5" top="5" right="5" bottom="5"/>
    <legend isVisible="false"></legend>
    <yAxis>
    <limits index="1" min="75" max="76" color="red"/>
    <limits index="2" min="50" max="51" color="yellow"/>
    </yAxis>
    </frameChart>'>
    
    <cfchart format="flash" chartwidth="875" chartheight="400" scalefrom="0" scaleto="100" style="#xmlStyle#" xaxistitle="Date" yaxistitle="Score">
        <cfchartseries type="line" query="myQyery" itemcolumn="myDate" valuecolumn="myScore"  seriescolor="00AEEF"/>
    </cfchart>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some inexplicable reason, when the following was removed from the frame tag the lines showed up.

```
isHStripVisible="true" stripColor="##F0F9FF"
```

If anyone can shed some light on this strange behavior I'd appreciate it!